# SQL Using an OBJECT as parameter for an ORDER mthod

Tags: sql, oracle, methods, plsql

I have a TYPE called Employee which has an ORDER method which takes an Employee as a parameter. I have created a table of Employee and inserted some data. I am trying to test this ORDER method using SELECT however i am having difficulty satisfying the parameter. here is my code

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Employee AS OBJECT(
  EmpID           VARCHAR(15),
   eName           VARCHAR(30),
   ePhone          NUMBER,
   eAddress        VARCHAR(15),
   ePosition       VARCHAR(15),
   eHireDt         DATE,
   salary          NUMBER,
   ORDER MEMBER FUNCTION orderSalary (e Employee) RETURN NUMBER)
NOT FINAL;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY Employee AS
   ORDER MEMBER FUNCTION orderSalary(e Employee) return number IS
   BEGIN
      IF(self.salary > e.salary) then
         return(1);
      ELSIF (self.salary < e.salary) then
         return(-1);
        ELSE
            return(0);
      END IF;
   END;
END;
/

CREATE TABLE Emp OF Employee (EmpID PRIMARY KEY)
OBJECT IDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY;


insert into Emp values('001','kabir',6477732272,'Pharmacy','clerk','2016-03-28',2000);
```

Here is the line that is giving me trouble:

```
SELECT p.orderSalary(Employee s) FROM Emp p;
```

All i need to do is test this method to make sure it works, is there any way i can create an instance of Employee to use as a parameter, or perhaps take a row from the Emp table? Thanks!

Comment: what error code are you getting?

Comment: This is the error message: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: Using a string literal for a to initialise a `DATE` type will only work when the format matches the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`. As soon as the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` changes (or you migrate to another server with different parameters) the query will stop working (but you will not have changed the code). It is better to use a date literal like `DATE '2016-03-28'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT p.orderSalary( VALUE( p ) ) FROM Emp p;
```

Or:

```
SELECT p.orderSalary( DEREF( REF( p ) ) ) FROM Emp p;
```

Or:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
  e1 EMPLOYEE := NEW EMPLOYEE('001','kabir',6477732272,'Pharmacy','clerk',DATE '2016-03-28',2000);
  e2 EMPLOYEE := NEW EMPLOYEE('002','bob',1234567890,'Library','assistant',DATE '2016-03-07',1000);
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( e1.orderSalary( e2 ) );
END;
/
```

**Update - Select different rows**:

```
insert into Emp values('001','kabir',6477732272,'Pharmacy','clerk','2016-03-28',2000);
insert into Emp values('002','bob',1234567890,'Library','assistant',DATE '2016-03-07',1000);

SELECT e1.ename AS name1,
       e2.ename AS name2,
       e1.orderSalary( VALUE( e2 ) )
FROM   Emp e1
       CROSS JOIN Emp e2;
```

**Outputs**:

```
NAME1  NAME2  E1.ORDERSALARY(VALUE(E2))
------ ------ -------------------------
kabir  kabir                          0 
kabir  bob                            1 
bob    kabir                         -1 
bob    bob                            0
```

Comment: The two SELECT statements you gave work, and produce output. Im not exactly sure what is going on; but based on the output i think that both the object being selected and the parameter are identical. Is there any way to use a different row from Emp table as the parameter (similar to the third option you posted) Thanks!!

Comment: @MassimoScocco Updated with another example

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!